# Three.js basics – Can't find variable – GLTFLoader animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, gltf

I’ve got very basic knowledge of JS. Following three.js docs [Loading 3D models](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models) I have succesfully rendered 3D object and centered it:

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load( 'Duck.gltf', function ( duck ) {
    
    const model = duck.scene
    const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( model );
    const center = new THREE.Vector3();
    box.getCenter( center );
    model.position.sub( center ); // center the model
    scene.add( model );

}, undefined, function ( error ) {

    console.error( error );

} );
```

I would like to animate it now, begining with simple rotation:

```
/**
 * Animate
 */

const clock = new THREE.Clock()

const tick = () =>
{

    const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()

    // Update objects
    model.rotation.y = .5 * elapsedTime

    // Update Orbital Controls
    // controls.update()

    // Render
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    // Call tick again on the next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick()
```

But the problem is console returns:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared model variable inside the functional scope, try to declare it outside

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
let model, box, center;

loader.load( 'Duck.gltf', function ( duck ) {
    
    model = duck.scene
    box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( model );
    center = new THREE.Vector3();
    box.getCenter( center );
    model.position.sub( center ); // center the model
    scene.add( model );

}, undefined, function ( error ) {
    console.error( error );
} );
```

Hopefully, this will work!

**Edited**

as @prisoner849 suggested in the comments

```
const clock = new THREE.Clock()
const tick = () =>
{
    const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()
    // Update objects
    if (model) {
       model.rotation.y = .5 * elapsedTime
    }
    // Update Orbital Controls
    // controls.update()
    // Render
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
    // Call tick again on the next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick()
```

Comment: And check, if `model` is not null, in animation loop, as the model highly likely won't be loaded yet, when the loop starts: `if (model) {model.rotation.y = .5 * elapsedTime}`

Comment: Yes @prisoner849, you are right!

Comment: Would be nice if you would describe why